# Programmatically pressing Alt 0 with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is run a script (JS) that selects a test box. It's ID field name is `JMan`. Once it selects that field I am trying to programmatically have my code perform the key combination `ALT+0` and then delay itself for 5 seconds. By the way I'm performing this in the IE browser.

```
function myFunction() {
    var keyboardEvent = document.createEvent("keyboardEvent").;
    document.getElementById("JMan");
}
var keyboardEvent = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
var initMethod = typeof keyboardEvent.initKeyboardEvent !== 'undefined' ? "initKeyboardEvent" : "initKeyEvent";


keyboardEvent[initMethod](
    "keydown", // event type : keydown, keyup, keypress
    true, // bubbles
    true, // cancelable
    window, // viewArg: should be window
    false, // ctrlKeyArg
    true, // altKeyArgenter code here
    false, // shiftKeyArg
    false, // metaKeyArg
    48, // keyCodeArg : unsigned long the virtual key code, else 0
    0 // charCodeArgs : unsigned long the Unicode character associated with the depressed key, else 0
);
document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
```

Comment: What is Alt + 0 supposed to do?

Comment: Once the JMan field is selected and ALT 0 is initiated it opens another mini window. Sorry if they are any mistakes or if im asking something obvious. im new to JS and usually try to use selenium to do this but the project requires JS and I.E. to be used.

Answer (score 1):

The detection event handler is a no-frills method of detecting Alt-0.  You might consider more sophisticated checking to do things like determine if another key was pressed between the Alt and 0 (i.e this code will treat `Alt-1-0` as if it were `Alt-0` or `Ctrl-Alt-0` as if it were `Alt-0`)(At least it checks if you hold down Alt-0).  This is mainly because key events differ considerably between browsers and I wanted to make something that will hopefully work on the majority.

The button in this example fires a minimal "Alt-0" event designed for the event handler to catch (or you should be able to type Alt-0 into the window).

```js
function fireAlt0() {
    console.log("firing event");
    window.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keydown", { key: "0", altKey: true }));
}

function detectAlt0(event) {
    if ("keydown" == event.type) { // we might want to use the same function for any of ( keydown, keypress, keyup ) events
        if (event.key == "0" && event.altKey && !event.repeat) {
            console.log("Open a window!");
        }
    }
}
    
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // Use keydown because keypress won't fire for the Alt-0 combination (since it doesn't produce a visible character)
    window.addEventListener("keydown", detectAlt0, false);
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", fireAlt0, false);
}, false);
```

```html
<button id="button">fireAlt0</button>
```